# How to change table row color using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have managed to insert a new row after finding the `<td>` class name using the jQuery. Now I need to change the row background color of that `<td>`. I tried many ways and also tried to use `closest('tr')` to find the row, but it failed. I tested to change the `<td>` color.

How do I change the row color?

Here is my jQuery code:

```
function jQueryShowWarning() {
    $('.hideClass').each(function() {                    
        $(this).css("background-color", "blue");                
        $('<tr width=100%;><td colspan="18" bgcolor="#00FF00"><div  style="background-color: #9999ff;"><font color="red">*test</font></div></td></tr>').insertAfter($(this).parent());      

        //this line doesn’t work                    
        $(this).parent().css("background-color", "red");
        //this line doesn’t work
        $(this).parent().closest('tr').css("background-color", "green");
        //this line doesn't work
        $(this).closest('tr').css("background-color", "red"); 
    });
}
```

After you Louis code, the image is:

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you use CSS to style the last row of the table, or do you only want to colour it red when a new row has been added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is probably to change all of the <td> inside the <tr>, so your selector should go along the lines of
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td').css('background-color', 'red')

assuming $(this) is a child element of the row for which you want to change the background color

Comment: thanks. It work but there is a white color between the tr and my new row. Also the width of the new row is little bit shorter than the old row. Would you tell me how to solve it. I want the new and old row has same background color without the gap. thanks. I post the image after I use you code.